# No module named installing Django App correctly

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-settings

I've recently started a Django project using 1.10+ and it is not clear to me how to 'correctly' reference the app from the project settings without specifying the full path.

I've read the [Django Application](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/applications/) Guide, but I'm still somewhat confused.

Given the structure below, how do I 'install' the `users` app 'correctly so that it's reusable later on.

[image]

This is my apps/user/app.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class UserConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'
    verbose_name = "User Catalogue"
```

In settings.py for the project I would like to do the following...

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # apps
    'apps.users',

]
```

I have also tried the following: `apps.users.apps.UserConfig` but get a No module named 'users' and even if it did work it's not as clean as using 'users'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you need to add into apps.`__init__`.py

```
from users.apps import UserConfig
```

or

```
default_app_config = 'users.apps.UserConfig'
```

Comment: Sorry, if this is stupid question, but by added ``default_app_config`` and users.apps.UserConfig etc that would mean I would need to change this everytime in every app to reuse 'users' app again? right?

Comment: That will cause UserConfig to be used when INSTALLED_APPS just contains 'users'. This allows you to make use of AppConfig features without requiring your users to update their INSTALLED_APPS setting. Besides this use case, it’s best to avoid using default_app_config and instead specify the app config class in INSTALLED_APPS as described next.

Comment: also you can do like this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/applications/#for-application-users

Comment: I have just tried ``user_product.apps.users.apps.UserConfig`` in the settings.py and I get  No module named 'users', why? I assumed without doing above this would work regardless?

Comment: actually that error is coming from the config sorry ``name = 'users'`` =  No module named 'users'

Comment: It can depends on how you created your `users` app, and name to your `users` app can be like that `user_product.apps.users`  in apps/user/app.py file